# SVN get the last commit message offline

Tags: git, svn, jenkins

Is there a way to get the last commit message without access to the repo? `svn log --limit 1` tries to connect to the repo.

EDIT: I have credentials setup and using them to check out the source.

What I'm trying to achieve, is to get Jenkins triggering another job depending on the commit message, i.e. if it contains the string "#build" start job X. My attempt was to parse it in a Shell Build Step and execute a job depending on its outcome. But since I don't have anonymous access to the repo and don't want to embed credentials in the shell script, I have no idea how to achieve this.

Next would be git..

Comment: You must have some credentials to actually update the repo in Jenkins? You're right git stores this history locally but it's in the same position: it can't update without credentials either. Can you not arrange enough access to the repo with its admin for your Jenkins server?

Comment: I'm in possession of some credentials, the problem is, that I dont want them in clear text in my shell script which parses the commit message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what [**Jenkins Credentials**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin) plugin is for.

You configure credentials securely on Jenkins Global Configuration, and let the job reference that. No need to write anything in the script.

***Edit:***
To securely use a password from within a shell step

- Install [**EnvInject plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin).
- Under **Jenkins Global Configuration**, find **Global Passwords** section.
- Add a **name** (this will be the environment variable name) and **password** (will be starred **** ).
- Under **Job Configuration**, find **Build Environment** section.
- Checkmark **Inject passwords to the build as environment variables**.
- Then checkmark **Global passwords**.

In any build step, you can now use `$name` (as defined earlier) to refer to a password as you would if you were typing it in plain text.

- The password variable is injected only at job execution time (typing `$name` on command line of the server by itself will not produce anything, and like all Jenkins variables, it is not persistent).
- The job console log will show `****` instead of password, if it appears.
- You could configure passwords per job, rather than globally, so that other jobs can't use it.

The only security concern is that if someone has **administrative permissions to configure your job**, they can write `echo $name > secretpassword.txt` into a build step, and then review the file in the workspace. But you should be careful who you assign administrative rights to.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but my question is how to get the lst commit message out of it. I use credentials for checking out the source, but then I want to check if the commit message contains "#build" or something.

Comment: Edited with alternate method

Answer (score 0):

I believe any action on a SVN repository uses the SVN repository's credential settings. However, if you have access on the server where the SVN repository is being hosted, you could create a own script to read out `{repository-root}/db/revprops` folder. Here you can find all the revision commit messages.

Comment: If you have read access to the repo, you can just use the standard SVN client with a `file://` URL to do the log for you, and that will bypass any authentication added by Apache or svnserve.

Comment: actually i dont have any access to the SVN server itself