# Jenkins can checkout svn repositories, but it can't run svn info "URL" in windows batch command window

Tags: svn, jenkins

I have a jenkins job that will checkout from repositories no problem.  Once the checkout is complete the first part of my job is to execute "svn info "URL" ".  When it tries to do this it will hang on the "authentication realm" syntax shown below, until I manually abort.  I don't believe this is an svn password caching issue because it is able to perform checkouts just fine.

svn info "URL"

Authentication realm: <https://svn-zz.asdf.com:443> wandisco

Password for 'b2345': Build was aborted

Aborted by

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins Checkout uses credentials stored within Jenkins to perform the checkout. This is part of the job setup.

When you then execute a Build Step with `svn` command, that's not part of the job setup, and therefore does not use Jenkins stored credentials.

If you need to use `svn` in a Build Step, you've got to either:

- Provide it with the credentials in the command line itself,
- Cache credentials on the OS level (under Jenkins user),
- Or configure global credentials and use that inside the Build Step, as described below:
  **[SVN get the last commit message offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099005/svn-get-the-last-commit-message-offline/26103757#26103757)**