# hiding your password in java class file for a test case

Tags: java, testing, selenium, jenkins, information-hiding

I am trying to write a selenium test case which will be put on company jenkins server where all the employee will have access to every java files I create.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("http://somesite.com");

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 



    WebElement userName=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='username']"));
    userName.clear();
    userName.sendKeys("someName@somecompany.com");

    WebElement password=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']"));
    passwordclear();
    password.sendKeys("password");
    password.submit();

   driver.quit();
```

What I want to do is not show the "password" there, I don't want other employees to see my password.
Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 2):

You could always encrypt it or base64 it or something so it isn't at least in plain text, but to be honest any sort of hardcoded password encryption can be reversed if they have / can see the source code.

Comment: You could also use java's [Console](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) class's [readPassword()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readPassword()) method and enter it when you run test cases.

Comment: @user3792255 Since i can't comment on the other thread as i don't have any reputation, i feel as if it  may help to point out that a coworker could just as easily run that exe and get your password, so i don't know if it's a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was thinking about it and like you said base64 or encryption are easily reversible.
I found a way by using AutoIT. So instead of sending characters (encryted or not) to the webelement,
I created a .exe file and did this

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("password.exe");

It worked fiawlessly. I know it is hard to decompile .exe file.

So do you think it is the best solution?

Comment: Not sure if that's the absolute best, but that's definitely a good way to at least hide your password. For even more protection, you could store the password as an encrypted string in the exe's source code, then decrypt it at the exe's runtime.

Comment: @user3792255 Could You show me how you did it? I also want to hide my password. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the test will only be run from Jenkins, you could use a Jenkins environment variable to store the password.

Jenkins supports password environment variables that will be hidden **`***`** even in the console log. This password could be configured globally (available to all jobs) or per-job (in which case only people with access to configure that particular job could potentially view the password, and even then not directly.

I had explained in detail how to configure this [**in this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099005/svn-get-the-last-commit-message-offline/26103757#26103757)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own function for Encryption and Description to supply protected value, in separate class and use a reference while supplying value in concerned field.